# Is there any performance difference between Autowire by type and Autowire by name

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I have changed my project to use **annotations instead of xml file**, but it increases application deploy time. Now I am looking for ways to reduce it.

Is there any performance difference between **Autowire by type** and **Autowire by name** ?

Any other suggestions to reduce deploy time are warmly welcome

Answer (score 1):

Similar question was asked sometime back you can refer to the below link for the answer:
[spring-wiring-by-type-is-slower-by-magnitude-than-wiring-by-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429612/spring-wiring-by-type-is-slower-by-magnitude-than-wiring-by-name)

It appears that the autowire by type has additional compatibility check to perform and is therefore inherently slower than its by name equivalent. There was a fix for this in Spring 3.1.2 and 3.2 but remains somewhat slower. Most applications doing this initialisation at startup, it isn't a big issue and brings more safety to the application.